# Wordpress lost link after theme update. [Enfold Theme]

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm by no means a coder or programmer but i have enough to understand my part and fix small issues or adjust look with basic CSS, and so friend of mine asked me for help and here i am two days later asking you)

There is a [Website](http://vcmt.ca) running Enfold theme which recently were updated and so was lost custom image link at right part of header made by someone-else.

I have restored link code from [Cached](https://web.archive.org/web/20160131134135/http://vcmt.ca/) version of website but have no real understanding how and where to add it back to theme templates. Would appreciate any help, solution, link, advice.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, since I don't have Enfold theme (the best would be to ask on the official support), but in your div `#header_main` in the `.inner-container`, you had after the `#advanced_menu_toggle` this piece of code:

```
<a href="https://edu.utopiaacademy.com/login" class="canvas" style="float:right"><img src="http://vcmt.ca/wp-content/themes/enfold/images/layout/canvas.jpg" alt="canvas" style="max-height:70px;"></a>
```

Just open the `.php` file that has the header in it, and paste this code back in. Since the `canvas.jpg` was located in the `/images` folder of the theme, that is also gone, so my recommendation is to download the image from the cached version if you can and put it back in the image folder.

Also it would be better to make changes to child theme, so that you can update the functionality of the theme, without loosing any custom added modification, like this site had.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning on changing the CSS in any WordPress Theme, you want to make sure that you have a child theme installed. The child theme allows you to change/overwrite the CSS and Theme Functions on the theme without losing those changes everytime the theme updates.

You can download the Enfold Child Theme Here:

https://kriesi.at/documentation/enfold/how-to-install-enfold-theme/#why-child-theme

...and if you need to add HTML to the header, you can do so by duplicating the header file from the theme, adding a header file to the child theme, and making your changes in the child theme header file.

Hope this Helps!